# How would you improve and optimize a manual encoding like this?

Tags: machine-learning, pandas

df.features is like a list of features in each row.
First I set all those encoded to 0, and then did this:

```
for index, row in df.features.iteritems():
if type(row) == str:
    if 'Academia' in row:
        df.academia.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Churrasqueira' in row:
        df.churrasqueira.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Cinema' in row:
        df.cinema.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Espaço gourmet' in row:
        df.espaco_gourmet.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Espaço verde / Parque' in row:
        df.parque.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Gramado' in row:
        df.gramado.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Jardim' in row:
        df.jardim.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Piscina' in row:
        df.piscina.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Playground' in row:
        df.playground.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Quadra de tênis' in row:
        df.quadra_tenis.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Quadra poliesportiva' in row:
        df.quadra_poli.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Quintal' in row:
        df.quintal.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Salão de festas' in row:
        df.salao_festas.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Salão de jogos' in row:
        df.salao_jogos.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Aquecimento' in row:
        df.aquecimento.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Ar condicionado' in row:
        df.ar_condicionado.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Conexão à internet' in row:
        df.internet.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Depósito' in row:
        df.deposito.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Elevador' in row:
        df.elevador.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Garagem' in row:
        df.garagem.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Lareira' in row:
        df.lareira.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Lavanderia' in row:
        df.lavanderia.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Massagem' in row:
        df.massagem.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Mobiliado' in row:
        df.mobiliado.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Recepção' in row:
        df.recepcao.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Sauna' in row:
        df.sauna.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Spa' in row:
        df.spa.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'TV a cabo' in row:
        df.tv_cabo.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Circuito de segurança' in row:
        df.circuito_seguranca.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Condomínio fechado' in row:
        df.condominio_fechado.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Interfone' in row:
        df.interfone.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Segurança 24h' in row:
        df.seguranca_24h.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Sistema de alarme' in row:
        df.alarme.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Vigia' in row:
        df.vigia.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Área de serviço' in row:
        df.area_servico.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Cozinha' in row:
        df.cozinha.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Escritório' in row:
        df.escritorio.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Sacada' in row:
        df.sacada.iloc[index] = 1
    if 'Varanda gourmet' in row:
        df.varanda_gourmet.iloc[index] = 1
```

Comment: Use [pandas.str.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and most efficient way to do it, is to use the One Hot Encoding [ScikitLearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

This is an example:

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
>>> enc = OneHotEncoder()
>>> enc.fit([[0, 0, 3], [1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]])  
OneHotEncoder(categorical_features='all', dtype=<... 'numpy.float64'>,
       handle_unknown='error', n_values='auto', sparse=True)
>>> enc.n_values_
array([2, 3, 4])
>>> enc.feature_indices_
array([0, 2, 5, 9])
>>> enc.transform([[0, 1, 1]]).toarray()
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```